# What is the best practice for using Anchors in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am somewhat a starter in web development, and I was wondering what is the best practice regarding using anchors in HTML design. I am currently designing and list where I can click on list items (`li`) and then using jQuery carry out a specific function. I am also using some images as clickable buttons, however, I was wondering if it's better practice to use anchors.

Comment: what are these anchors you talk about?

Comment: Are you by chance talking about using `<a>` tags for elements that are not real links but JavaScript-driven actions?

Comment: Anchor links is what he's referring to... I wouldn't think that needed to be clarified. 'Anchors' is a pretty well-known term isn't it?

Comment: @Lee not to the "I don't know vanilla JavaScript" Web 5.0 "dev" hipsters with React stickers on their Macbooks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **redirect from one page to another** that you should use **anchor tag**. However if you want to add event so its all depends upon markup.

Normally you can write inline js or css code **which is not a good practice**. Although you can use css or id and write your personalized code in separate JS file.

For example :-

```
<ul id="primary-nav">
  <li> Home </li>
  <li> About </li>
</ul>
```

After adding jquery on page, you can write down, required code :-

```
(function(){
  $("#primary-nav").on("click", function(){
    // Your Code;
  })
})
```

Some example of best practices is as under :-

> HTML boilerplate

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
    <meta name="description" content="goes here..."/>
    <meta name="keywords" content="keyword 1, keyword 2"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="robots"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="your-single-deployment-stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-144x144-precomposed.png">
    <!-- JS Links should sit on the bottom of the page! -->
</head>
<body>
... content
<script src="yourJavascript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

> CSS

Example of code with **bad names**

```
.s-scr {
  overflow: auto;
}
.cb {
  background: #000;
}
```

Example of code with **better names**

```
.is-scrollable {
  overflow: auto;
}
.column-body {
  background: #000;
}
```

Example of code with **bad names**

```
.right-red {
  float: right;
  color: red;
}
```

Example of code with **better names**

```
.text-highlight {
  float: right;
  color: red;
}
```

> JavaScript

```
//avoid repeating var in variable declaration
var foo;
var bar;
var lorem;
var ipsum;

//comma seperated variable declarations
var foo,
    bar,
    lorem,
    ipsum;
```

Avoid defining in multiple steps

```
var foo = {};

foo.prop = 'bar';

foo.method = function() {};

//defined in a single assignment
var foo = {   
  prop: 'bar',    
  method: function() {}
}
```

To avoid polluting global namespace, use below snippet

```
(function( window, undefined ) {
  var foo = 1; //private variable

})( window );
```

Checkout my other posts on GitHub to learn best practice i.e., [www.github.com/ananddeepsingh](https://github.com/ananddeepsingh)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it is very simple ie. 'onclick' event of javascript. This you can use it on any element of the DOM.

Eg :

```
<div onclick="alert('Hey this is working')">Click me</div>
```